# PHP mail encoding

Tags: php, email

there is a simple PHP code, I want to modify it, because it can't show me sylfaen letters. Instead sylfaen there are unknown symbols, like : **áƒ›áƒ˜áƒ¨áƒ** in my inbox.
Please help me.

```
<?php

$emailTo = "contact@address.com";
$name = $_POST["name"]; 
$emailFrom = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$subject = "From Website!";

if( !empty( $_POST ) ) {
    $body  = "Name: " . $name . "\n\n";
    $body .= "Email: " . $emailFrom . "\n\n";
    $body .= "Message:\n" . $message;
    $body  = wordwrap($body, 70);

    $header = "From: " . $emailFrom . "\nReply-To: " . $emailFrom. "\n\n" ;          

    if( mail( $emailTo, $subject, $body, $header) ) {
        echo( "result=Form sent successfully" );

    } else {
        echo( "result=There was a problem sending the form" );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: which encoding is the source file? is there any encoding tag in it?

Comment: There is only this code in PHP file, there is no any HTML head in it. I am using this form for AS3 flash website

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Content-type:` header and other associated MIME headers.  Without access to your message, we can't tell you what they should be, but this could be a starting point:

```
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-transfer-encoding: 8bit
```

If you can use a proper content transfer encoding, that would be preferable.  Maybe your content is `text/html` not `text/plain`?  You should probably be using PHPmail() rather than the low-level functions.  Etc.  This is a FAQ; look at the near-duplicates for more background.

Comment: So I am using this code for flash website, I have only PHP file without HTML head, I dont know PHP language, Please write below the working code. Thank you